# Blender animation's curled fingers are splayed-out when played in Unity

Tags: unity, animation, blender, skeletal-animation

I have exported my character into Unity and all the animations came with it. At first, I thought I was good to go but then I made a jogging animation. In blender the hands are gripped like this:

[image: Image of the character animations working in Blender.]

When this animation is exported to Unity the hands are no longer gripped and look like this:

[image: Image of the character animations not working in Unity]

Here are some more pictures showing the settings I have on my animation first in Blender:

[image]

Next in Unity:

[image]

So far I have tried:
Checking if the animations were updated in Unity (They were),
Reimporting the Unity model,
Looking through the animation properties in Blender,
Looking through the animation properties in Unity

I've been stuck on this for a few days now and I would appreciate some help as this is getting quite frustrating.

Comment: Are you using [the default Humanoid avatar](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AvatarCreationandSetup.html) to play back your animations in Unity - which does not have finger bones?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find this but my rig animation type is set to generic with avatar definition on no avatar and skin weights on 4 bones.

Comment: Searching "unity finger bones" leads me to [this video on fixing finger problems in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sixTAZSjnV4), which looks promising - anything useful for your problem in there?

Comment: That video didn't seem to be the problem. In the video, it was mostly shown that the finger bones are in the wrong position but on my rig, all the bones are in the correct place.